# grep parts of string with match and not match?

Tags: regex, grep

I have a log file which contains string `errorCode:null` or `errorCode:404` etc. I want to find all occurrences where errorCode is not null.

I use:

```
grep -i "errorcode" -A 10 -B 10  app.2020-.* | grep -v -i "errorCode:null"`, 

grep -v -i 'errorcode:[0-9]^4' -A 10 -B 10  app.2020-.*
```

but this is not the right regex match. How could this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `gnu-grep` then use a negative lookahead in regex as this with `-P` option:

```
grep -Pi 'errorcode(?!:null)' -A 10 -B 10 app.2020-.*
```

If you don't have `gnu grep` then try this `awk`:

```
awk '/errorcode/ && !/errorcode:null/' app.2020-.*
```

it would require more bit of code in `awk` to match equivalent of `-A 10 -B 10` options of `grep`.

Comment: can i pass multiple parameters to not  flag, like not null, not 111, not 1201?. I have gnu-grep it works thanks! 'errorcode(?!:null | ?!:111) is this fine??

Comment: Yes definitely possible using `grep -Pi 'errorcode(?!(:null|111|1201)\b)'`

Comment: starnagely this does gives me matches of errorCode:111, 1201

Comment: If you have `:` after `errorcode` then use: `grep -Pi 'errorcode(?!:(null|111|1201)\b)'`

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you are using `-A 10 -B 10`, I've just used the following command and everything is working fine:

```
grep -i "ErrorCode" test.txt | grep -v -i "Errorcode:null"
```

This the file content:

```
Errorcode:null
Errorcode:405
Errorcode:504
Nonsens
```

This is the output of the command:

```
Errorcode:405
Errorcode:504
```

Comment: well that's to get 10 lines after and before of match, thanks for this apprach

Comment: @Rahul: you're welcome, but when you add the preceding and the following 10 lines, aren't you afraid you might add the lines you don't want?

Comment: No, i actually want those lines to check what went wrong.